# Django-rest-framework api permission AllowAny authentication failed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have someViews like below:

```
class SomeView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
```

`settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',

),
...
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
),
...
```

}

And When I request without any `Authorization` header it works fine.
But When I add `Bearer Authorization` header it response

```
"detail": "Given token not valid for any token type",
"code": "token_not_valid",
```

I gave `permission_classes=[AllowAny]`.
**Why?** I thought there is no difference between **sending** or **not sending** `tokens`. Because I set `permission_class=[AllowAny]`.

In `ASP.NET` there is no like this problems. In `ASP.NET` If I set `AllowAny` permission
this endpoint open for everyone regardless of whether you send a `Token` or not.

**EDIT:**
And When I request `without` or `with` any `Authorization` header it works fine.
But When I add wrong `Authorization` header it gives authorization error
[image]

Comment: Authentication is different from permission. Your problem here is apparently related to authentication and thus has nothing to do with AllowAny (That's why you can access the view when you don't provide any type of authentication).

My guess would be that either the JWT token is invalid, or the JWT authentication is not properly implemented. You could edit your question to include your jwt authentication's implementation code so we can better assist you.

Comment: @Kauê Oliveira Yes you are right. I gave wrong token. But I want to work it when I gave wrong token too

Comment: @Kauê Oliveira How to pass `authentication` when I gave wrong token too. I want to pass it `anyway`. If there is a token or not. If token is `valid` or `not`. `Anyway`

Comment: If what you want is to remove authentication, replace your authentication class config wih this:  `'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],`. If you want to remove authentication for this view only, try setting this on your view `authentication_classes = []`.

Comment: @Kauê Oliveira this is (`authentication_classes = []`) not works

Answer (score 3):

**AllowAny** verify token if it sent and pass if not any. So, if you dont need to authenticate, clear permission_classes

```py
permission_classes = ([])
```

Answer (score 2):

I've confronted with similar issue. In one project, we have SET default permission classes as IsAuthenticated.

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
```

In that scenario, when given Authorization header, customer login view responses with 401. Login view should have been able to disregard Authorization header. How we solved the problem is as follows:

```
class CustomerLoginAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginCustomerRequestSerializer
    authentication_classes = ([])
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
```

You can also test it with given Test Case.

```
class TestCustomerLogin(TestCase):
  email = "a@a.com"
  password=  "123456"
  url = reverse("authorization/customer-login")

  def setUp(self) -> None:
      #Create a user
      self.user = User.objects.create_user(username=self.email,password=self.password)
      self.customer = Customer.objects.create(user=self.user,name="Test Customer")

  def tearDown(self) -> None:
      self.user.delete()
      self.customer.delete()

  def test_correct_account_with_token(self):
      token = "2c0d19194c042d7fe976fb9240915007a402b3d8228a1958b59b54daf816fb84"
      headers = {'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': f'Token {token}'}
      body = {"email": self.email, "password": self.password}
      response = self.client.post(self.url,body,format="json",**headers)
      self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Hope it also works well in your case.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I inserted the refresh token rather than the access token. Before you do anything else, make sure you pass in the correct token.